# How to run shadun/ci command? Giving error "package.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js

The error message I encountering indicates that the `npx shadcn-ui@latest init` command is trying to read the `package.json` file in your project directory but cannot find it. This file is essential for initializing a Node.js project.

```
Error: package.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Reactjs Project\package.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:581:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:457:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\125ee17d583c4e03\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:50:22)
    at _e (file:///C:/Users/Mayank/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5248)
    at _t (file:///C:/Users/Mayank/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5379)
    at file:///C:/Users/Mayank/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5606
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Reactjs Project\\package.json'
}

npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

try to run this in my terminal but showing error. How can I fix this error?

[image]